# JavaFX - Confusing FadeTransition behaviour

Tags: java, css, javafx-8

I am trying to create a menu scene for an application using FXML and CSS. The idea is that when you press the "NEW" button, two more buttons appear underneath it while the rest of the buttons slide downwards. I have also tried to implement a system where if you press the "NEW" button again, it will have a reverse effect.

In practise, the first time the "NEW" button is pressed everything goes as planned: the two buttons fade in and the other buttons slide down. However, the second time the translation occurs but not the fade out...

I am thoroughly confused and would love some help! Here's the code from the controller file:

```
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.animation.ParallelTransition;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class Menu implements ControlledScene {
private SceneController controller;

@FXML private Button newButton;
@FXML private Button continueButton;
@FXML private Button instructionsButton;
@FXML private Button settingsButton;
@FXML private Button exitButton;
@FXML private HBox subMenu;
@FXML private VBox translateMenu;

@FXML private void newButtonAction() {
    if (subMenuVisible.equals(false)) {
        subMenu.setVisible(true);

        FadeTransition fadeIn = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(300), subMenu);
        fadeIn.setFromValue(0.0);
        fadeIn.setToValue(1.0);

        TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), translateMenu);
        translate.setByY(100);

        ParallelTransition transitions = new ParallelTransition(translate, fadeIn);
        transitions.play();

        subMenuVisible = true;

    } else {
        FadeTransition fadeOut = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(300), subMenu);
        fadeOut.setFromValue(1.0);
        fadeOut.setToValue(0.0);

        TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), translateMenu);
        translate.setByY(-100);

        ParallelTransition transitions = new ParallelTransition(translate, fadeOut);
        transitions.play();

        subMenu.setVisible(false);
        subMenuVisible = false;
    }
}
```

The FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>

<GridPane fx:controller="timesup.menu.Menu" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" styleClass="grid">

<stylesheets>
    <URL value="@Menu.css" />
</stylesheets>

<Text text="Title!" id="title"
    GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.halignment="center" GridPane.valignment="center" />

<Button text="NEW" fx:id="newButton" onAction="#newButtonAction"
    GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="center" GridPane.valignment="center" />

<HBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:id="subMenu" styleClass="subMenu" spacing="10"
    GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="center" GridPane.valignment="center" >
    <Button text="Random Words" id="randomWordsButton" onAction="#randomWordsButtonAction" />
    <Button text="Write your own" id="writeWordsButton" onAction="#writeWordsButtonAction" />
</HBox>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:id="translateMenu" spacing="10"
    GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="center" GridPane.valignment="center" >
    <Button text="CONTINUE" fx:id="continueButton" onAction="#continueButtonAction" />
    <Button text="INSTRUCTIONS" fx:id="instructionsButton" onAction="#instructionsButtonAction" />
    <Button text="SETTINGS" fx:id="settingsButton" onAction="#settingsButtonAction" />
    <Button text="EXIT" fx:id="exitButton" GridPane.columnIndex="0"     onAction="#exitButtonAction" />
</VBox>

</GridPane>
```

And the CSS file for good measure:

```
.grid {
-fx-background-color: white;
-fx-grid-lines-visible: true;
-fx-padding: 25;
-fx-vgap: 10;
-fx-alignment: center;
-fx-halignment: center;
}

#title {
    -fx-font-size: 100px;
    -fx-font-family: "Impact";
} 

.button {
    -fx-font-size: 30px;
    -fx-font-family: "Impact";
    -fx-cursor: hand;
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-border-radius: 20px;
    -fx-border-width: 3px;
    -fx-background-radius: 20px;
}

.subMenu {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.button:hover {
    -fx-border-color: red;
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}

.vbox {
    -fx-spacing: 10;
    -fx-halignment: center;
}
```

Thank you for your help!